# Include file generate warning

Tags: php

I have an INCLUDE file to manage user permissions (include/permission.php)

```
 // PERM
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mod_permission WHERE usuer_id=".$_SESSION['user_id']);
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH) or die(mysql_error());

 $perm_add = $row['perm_add'];       
 $perm_edit = $row['perm_edit'];       
 $perm_del = $row['perm_del'];
```

But when i try to include i have error:

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

I'm like to make something this:

File: example.php

```
<?php
include_once "include/db_conn.php";
include_once "include/permission.php";

if ($perm_add != "1") {
    header("Location: $url/dash.php?error=1"); exit;
}
?>
```

Where do I wrong?
Thanks ALL for helping!!!

Comment: Your query is failing and returning Boolean `FALSE`

Comment: likely because `usuer_id` is not the name of the field...

Comment: When `mysql_query()` returns false, you need to `die($mysql_error());` to see the error message. Look at all the **Related** questions.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably have a MySQL Syntax Error, probably as stated in the comments because user_id is mispelled.

```
$result = mysql_query(
         "SELECT * FROM mod_permission WHERE usuer_id=".$_SESSION['user_id']
         ) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH) or die(mysql_error());
```

Also refrain from using this deprecated mysql_* extension as it won't be supported in near future php versions!

Comment: Note that `die` isn't necessarily the best way of handling errors once you're done with debugging. It is a little ... fatal ...

Comment: its a little debug =)

Comment: Yeah, meant it as advice to the OP, not a criticism of the answer; was just editing the comment to clarify :)